# php display <img src /> in Joomla based on link in Database column

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to display an image linked to a user that is logged in based on a Joomla site.

The PHP code I am using is as follows:

```
<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();

$username = $user->username;

echo '<img src="$user->picture" />'
;
?>
```

During my testing and troubleshooting, I tested without the image source tag and I received the call back from my database table labeled Images/LOGO.jpg which displayed as a string on my front end.

when I use the Image source again and replace $user->picture with the same string from the DB column, the image returns 100%.

By leaving the code as per above the page loads successfully but no image is returned.

Thanks,

Comment: Try echo '<img src="'.$user->Picture.'" />'

Comment: an try /Images/logo as absolute with begining slash

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have tried both and also updated my reference in the db to be /Images/LOGO.jpg but still loads the page without displaying the image.

Comment: what is printed in the source code?

Comment: Got it working with Poiz Solution below and after checking the image source i had to add the / so thanks very much for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bug is quite obvious....`echo '<img src="$user->picture" />'`
Did you notice anything unusual in the Snippet above?
Here is a Hint: Try this: `<?php $var="test"; echo '$var'; ?>`
 What did you get?
Sure you got it all back as is: VERBATIM - `$var` instead of the expected **test**.
 So here's the Catch:

> Any variable within Single Quotes in PHP would NOT expand/evaluate to a Value...
> You'd just get the Variable back: Verbatim

Rather do it like so:

```
    <?php
        $user       = JFactory::getUser();
        $username   = $user->username;
        // NOTICE THE DOUBLE QUOTES SURROUNDING THE "<img... />" TAG
        // THOUGH NOT SO IMPORTANT, BUT NOTICE ALSO THE BRACES AROUND
        // {$user->picture}
        echo "<img src='{$user->picture}' />";
```

By the way; in Joomla, you could get the User-Avatar like so:

```
    <?php
        // USE jimport TO PULL IN THE PROFILE PICTURE CLASS
        jimport('profilepicture.profilepicture');

        // GET THE USER OBJECT LIKE YOU ALREADY DID
        $user       = JFactory::getUser();

        // CREATE A NEW INSTANCE OF THE ProfilePicture CLASS PASSING IT THE USER ID
        $userPix    = new ProfilePicture($user->get('id'));

        // ECHO OUT THE ENTIRE HTML FOR THE USER PROFILE PICTURE
        echo $userPix->toHTML();
```

Cheers & Good-Luck, Mate!  ☝️✌️

Answer (score 0):

single quote does not print the var value, change it to
`"<img src=\"$user->picture\" />"`